# How to recognize voice for a specific sentence and raise proper action if voice recognized?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extending Android's Voice Search app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056003/extending-androids-voice-search-app)

How to recognize voice for a specific sentence and raise proper action if voice recognized?
e.g:
Sentence: "Please call Mr Mark"
if i speak "Please call Mr Mark" i want to raise relevant action..

How should i do it? Please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Extending Android's Voice Search app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056003/403455)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239617/403455) says,

> In a word, no. The app doesn't have the extension points you are
>   looking for. You would have to write your own app entirely, which is
>   something that others have done.

See this Android blog post for more info:  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html